# spaCy: spacy.tokens.doc.Doc to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, spacy

I have a Spacy model for text generation, and I want to create a pandas data frame with all the texts that my Spacy model produces in each iteration. How can I save the spacy.tokens.doc.Doc output into a pandas dataframe?

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
newDataSet=pd.dataframe()
docs = nlp.pipe(df['Text'])
syn_augmenter =augmenty.load('random_synonym_insertion.v1',level=0.1)
for doc in augmenty.docs(docs, augmenter=syn_augmenter, nlp=nlp):
    newDataSet=newDataSet.add(doc) # this produces an error
```

Comment: Please add a full example

Comment: What is the expected output, also a small toy example of input would be nice

Answer (score 0):

so you probably want to use DframCy library to make that happen. It is also recommended by SpaCy: https://spacy.io/universe/project/dframcy. A snippet I use is:

```
import spacy
from dframcy import DframCy
from tqdm import tqdm
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_trf')
dframcy = DframCy(nlp)

columns=["id", "text", "start", "end", "pos_", "tag_", "dep_", \
"head", "ent_type_", "lemma_", "lower_", "is_punct", "is_quote", "is_digit"]

def get_features(item):
    doc = dframcy.nlp(item[1]["discourse_text"])
    annotation_dataframe = dframcy.to_dataframe(doc, columns=columns)
    annotation_dataframe['index'] = item[0]
    return annotation_dataframe

results = []
for item in tqdm(df.iterrows(), total=df.shape[0]):
    results.append(get_features(item))

features = pd.concat(results)
features
```

So the `columns` object denotes what objects you want to have returned. This is parsed to dframcy is extract the features and return a nice dataframe per document. If you have a table of strings that you want to tokenize and get features from, you need to iterate over it. TQDM tracks the overall progress of your for-loop. Concatenating the list of dataframes (per doc) will give you a complete overview.

Comment: The Universe is a directory of packages provided to make things easier to find, not a list of explicit recommendations.